# Can't show results to JSON results in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a function success to the ajax method to JQuery. 
I works properly and I have a response but problems is trying to show the arrays in a table.

```
success:function(resp){
            var json =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp));
            console.log(json); 
            $("#table").append('<tr><td>Titulo</td>'+
            '<td>Consola</td>' + 
            '<td>Precio</td>');
            for (i=0;i<json.length; i++){
               $("#tbody").append('<tr>' + 
               '<td align="center" style="display: none;">' + json[i].titulo + '</td>'+
               '<td align="center" style="display: none;">' + json[i].consola + '</td>'+
               '<td align="center" style="display: none;">' + json[i].precio + '</td>'+'</tr>');
               } //cierre del for.
            $('#modal').click();
            }
```

my html is:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Lista de juegos disponibles</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table" id="table">
    </table>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the array in the console.log is:

```
[Array(2)]
0: Array(2)
0: {titulo: "Kingdom Hearts 2.5 HD remix", consola: "2", precio: "15990"}
1: {titulo: "Tales of Xillia 2", consola: "2", precio: "14990"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: why God why `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp))` :D

Comment: You are missing one array level. Do `var json = resp[0];`

Comment: what is console.log(resp) printing?

Comment: is printing this: [Array(4)]
0: Array(4)
0: {titulo: "God of War", consola: "1", precio: "29990"}
1: {titulo: "Read Dead Redemption 2", consola: "1", precio: "42990"}
2: {titulo: "Call of duty Advance Warfare", consola: "1", precio: "14990"}
3: {titulo: "Nier: Automata", consola: "1", precio: "24990"}

Answer (score 0):

@Angel Gomez

tr is created inside tbody you can use below code to achieve the same.

```
for (i=0;i<json.length; i++){
               $("#table>tbody").append('<tr>' + 
               '<td align="center" style="display: none;">' + json[i].titulo + '</td>'+
               '<td align="center" style="display: none;">' + json[i].consola + '</td>'+
               '<td align="center" style="display: none;">' + json[i].precio + '</td>'+'</tr>');
               }
```

Comment: hey, it did work for me checkout the link

http://jsfiddle.net/saurabhanand/f2mxks30/33/

Comment: or if that lint doesn't work use this https://codepen.io/saurabhanand3390/pen/QYNrqR